# How to migrate from PostgreSQL to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm installing [Moodle](http://moodle.org/) in an Amazon EC2 instance. Currently, there is a backup in from PostgreSQL 7.3 which I already migrated to PostgreSQL 9.1. However, I need convert this database to MySQL 5.5.12 to use Amazon RDS.

Are there any tools to do this?

I'm using [pg2mysql](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php) but maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Any particular problems you're having with pg2mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I migrate easily from MySQL to PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701744/how-do-i-migrate-easily-from-mysql-to-postgresql)

Comment: @derobert the problem with pg2mysql is the size of files from pg_dump

Comment: Please edit that into the question, being as specific as possible (e.g., "the pg_dump file is 2TB. pg2mysql doesn't seem able to handle this, crashing with a (something) exception / has been working on it for 3 days and isn't done / etc."). The edit link is located under the tags.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use EC2 with postgresql?  RDS isn't much more than a totally vanilla MySQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use pg2mysql for the schema and this script in python for the data:

https://gist.github.com/1483322

Answer (score 2):

I think the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701814/113527) in the question [How do I migrate easily from MySQL to PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701744/how-do-i-migrate-easily-from-mysql-to-postgresql) is applicable in this case: either automated tools like pg2mysql are sufficient, or your schema is complicated enough that you will need to migrate manually.